# How do i get this ios button to stay visible in the feed view after pushing to another view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How do i get this ios button to stay visible in the feed view after pushing to the profile view?
When i return to the feed (by the tabbed bar button), the original 'to profile' button is no longer visible in the feed view. 
This continues on each button i press, so the buttons all endup not visible (but still selectable, and visible shortly when clicked before preceding to view).

[image: iphone views]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain an array of feed indexes that are already selected in a singleton class.

```
NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Whenever you select a feed , you need to add the feed index to this array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [selectedIndexes addObject:INDEX];
}
```

In your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you need to check whether this index included in the array. If it contains in the array, you need to hidden the button.

Comment: thanks. is there a default class that all controllers already have scope to that one would normally put such a singleton in, or one would just create one and access it?

Comment: yes. you can use your appdelegate class for this.initialize the array in appdelegate and try [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate ] selectedIndexes]